# Facebook 404 file or directory not found

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404, share

I have an `e-commerce website` and I want to **share** a link on my **Facebook profile**.

When I do I get a **404 - File or Directory not found** even though the URL is working properly when you click on it. Below is what I see exactly:
[image]

I have tried:

1. To post the URL with https:// or without
2. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object
3. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

None of these solutions work!

The Sharing debugger shows this error:
[image]

But I don't understand how the error is legit since I have the parameters it's asking on my Page's Header tags.

[image]

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: _“What exactly is wrong?”_ - what the debug tool _told_ you, is what’s wrong. Your system responded to the request made by the Facebook scraper with a 404. Why - that is for you to figure out, no one here can do that for you from the outside.

Comment: I have tried to figure it out on my own first and I told you in my question what I have tried. The Warnings shown in the debug tool don't help me enough since I don't see og: parameters missing as it says.

Comment: _“since I don't see og: parameters missing”_ - that’s because you are looking in the wrong place … Your actual page might contain them, but Facebook did not _get_ that page in response from your system, it got a 404 status code – and that  was in all likelihood probably accompanied by some sort of 404 error _document_. And I doubt your site’s 404 error document actually contains these OG meta tags. The 404 is the actual error here, the others just _subsequent_ errors caused by that first one.

Comment: Oh I see! Now I'm starting to see in the right direction. Your comment helped but could you please give me some more guidance or what you would try to do in my case as an answer here? How can Facebook not get my page as a response and get a 404? It's really weird.

Comment: Check if you have any plugins/modules/whatever running, that try to block requests by “bad” bots. In most cases it is something like that, the scraper being classified as such, based on the User-Agent it sends not matching a real browser, or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem at some point and the issue was that the team who manages our server had **blocked** the **bots** of Facebook and other search engines from entering our website and they forgot to undo this! Have a look if this is the reason in your occasion.

Comment: Yes! This solved my problem! I have windows server and I found an option in the IIS where you can disable certain IPs to enter your website! Thank you a lot!